# Copy key value pair from one dictionary to another if the same key exists in both the dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider the two dictionaries below:

```
d1 = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
d2 = {'a':9,'d':10}
```

I would like the output to be:

```
{'a':9, 'b':2, 'c':3}
```

How could I do this with Python?

Comment: `b`, `c` and `d` aren't in both dictionaries.  Why are they in the output?

Comment: And `c` is not in both, why is it in the output? Your question is very unclear, please try and re-phrase it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

d1 = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
d2 = {'a':9,'d':10}

c = {k:(d2[k] if k in d2 else v) for k,v in d1.items()}

print(c)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 9, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in d1:
    if key in d2:
        d1[key] = d2[key]
```